# Elasticsearch's Common Terms Query, use and compatibility with query types

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently investigating the use of common terms query, and since the documentation is a little lacking (either that or I am not simply not finding any documentation on these issues) I am not entirely sure if certain operations are incompatible with common terms queries, or if I am doing it wrong.

I am currently on Elasticsearch version 0.90.5 in Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit.

Here's what I am observing:

- The query types match and match_phrase appear to be incompatible with use of the high_freq_operator, low_freq_operator, and minimum_should_match option. (e.g. `[match] query does not support [high_freq_operator]` and similar)
- and, or, and not (composite expressions) seem to produce broken underlying expressions when their component expressions specify use of common terms. (e.g. `[_na] filter malformed, must start with start_object`)
- span_term query seems to be incompatible with common terms queries. (e.g. `[span_term] query does not support [common]`)

My queries look this:

This one parses for example...

```
{   "query": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        "match_phrase": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            "subject": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                "common": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                    "body": {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                        "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        "query": "something not important"                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

This one fails to parse, citing "[match] query does not support [high_freq_operator]":

```
{"query": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        "match_phrase": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            "subject": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                "common": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                    "body": {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                        "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                        "high_freq_operator": "or",                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        "query": "something not important"                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

This one fails to parse, citing "filter malformed, must start with start_object":

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    "filter": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        "or": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                "query": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    "match": {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                        "subject": {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                            "common": {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                "body": {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                    "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,                                                                                                                                                                              
                                    "query": "PLEASE READ: something not important"                                                                                                                                                         
                                }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                            }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                "query": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    "range": {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                        "date": {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                            "to": "2009-12-31T23:59:59Z"                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have misunderstood the structure of queries.  Queries can either be "leaf" queries (which deal with an individual field or fields directly) or a "compound" query which wraps other queries, like the `bool` and `dis_max` queries.

A `common`-terms query is a leaf query in its own right, just like the `match`, `match_phrase`, `term` and `range` queries.  You can't embed the `common` query INSIDE another leaf query.

The `match` query (not the `match_phrase` nor the `match_phrase_prefix`) has been partially integrated with the `common`-terms query in that it supports the `cutoff_frequency` parameter.  It's a simple integration: if you specify the `cutoff_frequency` then the `match` query is rewritten internally as a `common` query.  If you want the full power of `common`-terms, then you need to use it directly.

So this `match` query:

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "subject": {
            "query": "some words to query",
            "cutoff_frequency": 0.001
         }
      }
   }
}
```

is the equivalent of this `common` query:

```
{
   "query": {
      "common": {
         "subject": {
            "query": "some words to query",
            "cutoff_frequency": 0.001
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The difference being that in the `common` query, there are a number of other knobs that you can twiddle, eg `high_freq_operator` etc

Comment: Thanks. Just as a note for anyone reading this response, I have found that match_phrase does support cutoff_frequency.

Comment: The match_phrase may not reject the parameter, but it doesn't take it into account: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/search/MatchQuery.java#L208

Answer (score 0):

For Elasticsearch **6.4**:

For example to join **common** with **filter** query use this:

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "common": {
          "task_content": {
            "query": "this is bonsai cool superb",
            "cutoff_frequency": 0.01,
            "high_freq_operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "subject_id": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "task_content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps for newer version.